# How do I move a shared_ptr object between containers with move semantics?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two vectors which contain pointers to shared objects in my program:

```
typedef shared_ptr<T> sp;
std::vector<sp> v1;
std::vector<sp> v2;
```

And sometimes I want to move an object of type *sp* from the end of v1 to the end of v2. This section of code is a significant bottleneck in my program, and since I have no need for the value in v1 after the move I was thinking that if I move them rather than copying I can avoid the extra counter increment/decrement, right? So here's what I've done:

```
// move constructor for new element of v2:
v2.emplace_back(v1.back());

// the move constructor should have made the element in v1 null:
assert(v1.back() == nullptr); // FAIL - why?

// now remove the dead element at the end of v1
v1.pop_back();
```

What have I done wrong here? Is this not the *right* way? BTW using a different pointer type is not an option - type T is quite unambiguously shared (just not in this particular instance!).

**EDIT:** Here is my implementation of David's solution:

```
// move constructor for new element of v2:
v2.emplace_back(std::move(v1.back()));

// the move constructor should have made the element in v1 null:
assert(v1.back() == nullptr); // ok!

// now remove the dead element at the end of v1
v1.pop_back();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not invoking the move constructor. Nothing about the `emplace_back` call makes it clear `v1` is no longer needed. You probably need a `std::move` in there.

You probably want:

```
v2.emplace_back(std::move(v1.back()));
v1.pop_back();
```

Comment: The move constructor for shared_ptr does guarantee that the source releases the ownership and is set to null.

Comment: As Timo already mentioned, it is guaranteed. [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) checks `get() != 0` and `std::shared_ptr` move ctor docs say `r.get() == 0.`

Comment: It seems to me like David and @Timo differ here. Does the move constructor kill the element or not? Doesn't std::move() only *force* move semantics that might already occur anyway? Sorry if these are numpy questions, I still don't really understand this stuff.

Comment: I'm inclined to leave this as the answer. I've added the std::move call but I'm still checking v2.back() == nullptr and it seems to be working. Is this not guaranteed behaviour? I've added David's modification to the OP.

Comment: @ausairman: The move constructor behaves as you expected, and most likely it is optimized so that no reference count increment/decrement take place. But `v2.emplace_back(v1.back());` invokes *copy constructor*, so the extra `move` call is needed to force the move.

Comment: @ausairman: I believe c++11 does specify that it becomes equivalent to a default-constructed shared pointer. (Answer updated.)